# jQuery Cycle 'destroy' command (and all other commands) ignored

Tags: jquery, jquery-cycle

I'm having an issue with jQuery cycle simply ignoring all commands (destory, stop etc.). There are a lot of other things going on on this page, which may be contributing, but I'm not sure how much example code is too much.

In a nutshell, I have two simultaneous slideshows that init on page load, and when '.video-trigger' is clicked, the cycle instances should be destroyed.  But on click, cycle keeps cycling (and covering up the video that is supposed to replace it).

I've tried every possible scenario I can think of to try to find the source — removing all the other javascript (just the cycle and destroy click event remaining), only attempting to call and destroy one of the two slideshows (instead of both), calling them in separate wrappers. I even removed both of those cycle instances and made a super simple "test" cycle and click event in a completely different part of the page, and that one also couldn't be destroyed.  Not sure what I'm missing.

The other jQuery plugin being used here is videojs, if that's of consequence.

This is all of the script except an unrelated fancybox with videos.  If it would help to include everything, let me know, but I think I may be including too much already.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){

    /// fading background images and video trigger
    $('#background-image-wrapper,#trigger-fade').cycle();

    // handle videos
    $('.video-trigger').click(function() {
        $('#background-image-wrapper,#trigger-fade').cycle('destroy');

        var vidName = $(this).attr('id');           
        var vidID = 'video_' + vidName;

        $('#background-image-wrapper').append('<div id="vid-cont" class="video-container"></div>');
        $('#vid-cont').append('<video id="' + vidID + '" class="video-js vjs-default-skin" preload="auto" data-setup="{}">' +
            '<source src="http://domain.com/wp-content/themes/sapporo/v/sapporo-'+ vidName +'.mp4" type="video/mp4">' +
            '<source src="http://domain.com/wp-content/themes/sapporo/v/sapporo-'+ vidName +'.ogv" type="video/ogg">' +
            '<source src="http://domain.com/wp-content/themes/sapporo/v/sapporo-'+ vidName +'.webm" type="video/webm">' +
            '</video>');

        //alert(vidID);
        _V_(vidID).ready(function(){
          var myPlayer = this;
          var aspectRatio = 9/16;
          function resizeVideoJS(){
              //var width = document.getElementById(myPlayer.id).parentElement.offsetWidth; // Get the parent element's actual width -- this wasn't working with lower versions of FF
              var width = document.getElementById('vid-cont').offsetWidth; // Get the parent element's actual width
              myPlayer.width(width).height( width * aspectRatio ); // Set width to fill parent element, Set height
          }
         resizeVideoJS(); // Initialize the function
         window.onresize = resizeVideoJS; // Call the function on resize

            $('#trigger-fade').fadeOut();
            $('#video-controls').fadeIn();
            $('.video-container').css('left', '0');
            myPlayer.volume(0);
            myPlayer.play(); //start playing the video
            var endedEvent = function(){ 
                $('#video-controls').fadeOut(function(){ $('#trigger-fade').fadeIn(); });
                $('.video-container').css('left', '-9999em'); 
                $('.background-image').fadeIn('slow'); 
            };
            myPlayer.addEvent("ended", endedEvent);

         $('#pause-video').click(function(){
            myPlayer.pause();
            $(this).fadeOut(function(){ $('#play-video').fadeIn(); });
         });
         $('#play-video').click(function(){
            myPlayer.play();
            $(this).fadeOut(function() { $('#pause-video').fadeIn(); });
         });
         $('#mute-video').click(function(){
            myPlayer.volume(0);
            $(this).fadeOut(function(){ $('#unmute-video').fadeIn(); });
         });
         $('#unmute-video').click(function(){
            myPlayer.volume(.7);
            $(this).fadeOut(function() { $('#mute-video').fadeIn(); });
         });
         $('#close-video').click(function(){
            myPlayer.pause();
            $('#video-controls').fadeOut(function(){ $('#trigger-fade').fadeIn(); });
            $('.video-container').css('left', '-9999em'); 
            $('.background-image').fadeIn('slow'); 
         });
       });
    });
   });
```

**UPDATE**:
I haven't come any closer to resolving the issue (and it happens regardless of if I use Cycle or Cycle2). I've implemented a workaround I'm not happy with (just hiding the slideshow, while it's still running while the video plays).  But what I did notice, after customizing cycle then trying to pause the same slideshow on a different click event, is when the command is triggered, the command isn't followed, but all of the custom options I previously set for cycle are overwritten.

i.e. 
If I start with:

```
    $('#background-image-wrapper,#trigger-fade').cycle({{timeout: 4000, speed: 7000}});
```

Then, use this on a click event:

```
    $('#background-image-wrapper,#trigger-fade').cycle('destroy');
```

or

```
    $('#background-image-wrapper,#trigger-fade').cycle('pause');
```

Then, rather than destroying or pausing, it basically just starts a new instance of Cycle as if 'destroy/pause' didn't exist.

Comment: Will you have errors in the console? Will a simple `$('#background-image-wrapper,#trigger-fade').hide()` (just to see if you got your selectors right) work?

Comment: Good questions, but nope., no errors in the console, and yes, hide works (selectors correct).

Answer (score 0):

I am having the same issue. The 'destroy' command seems to be completely ignored here:

http://brianleatart-art.com/

I only want one slideshow running at a time but since the 'destroy' command isn't working it keeps running slideshows that are hidden.

Answer (score -1):

I had a similar issue and for me, the solution was to store the cycle in a variable and call this variable to destroy it. Like this:

```
var mycycle = $('#background-image-wrapper,#trigger-fade').cycle();
...
mycycle.cycle('destroy');
```

Not sure if you still need this, but maybe someone will.